# Strange Errors on Archive Validation

Tags: ios, validation, xcode8

I've had an iOS project in fairly stable condition up until Xcode 8's public release. After a bit of confusion with the Migrator, I finally convinced the compiler that I did *not* want to go Swift 3 yet, and that my code was indeed valid Swift 2.3. Not sure if this at all relates to what the Organizer does in validating my long-awaited archive with some long-overdue fixes for iOS 10, but we'll see...

Anyway, I got Xcode to archive my latest build (which runs fine on my iPhone 5s by the way). I tell Organizer to "Validate..." in preparation for an upload to iTunes Connect. After a good deal of doing its thing, it finally spits this at me:

[image: Archive validation failed with errors:]

Been at this for three days now. Application Loader gives me something similar, but not much more helpful:

[image: The asset catalog at '$path' can't contain...]

Following the suggestions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39475232/3799856), I find that every single one of my compiled assets read as sRGB, *not* 16-bit, or P3. Aside: When does an API analysis file get "too large"? I mean, sure I use Apple's APIs a lot, but I can't be alone in that. That's what they're for, right?

I've tried (almost) everything I can think of. I've redone my code signing a dozen different ways, read and recombobulated the build settings wherever I thought could be relevant, and tried every combination of bitcode and symbol inclusion available to me. Just about everything I could come up with short of migrating to Swift 3! Could that really be my solution? It's a rather big jump, and with the time I have, I'd prefer to get this working build out to my users before I'm slammed too hard to shore up the updated codebase.

I can't seem to find anything on "ITunesSoftwareServiceAuthenticationErrorDomain", or this mysterious "error 434". The only reference I've found so far leads to a [dead StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193705/). Really wish the author hadn't removed it... Wonder if he found his answer?

So my question is as follows: What am I doing wrong to get these errors, and how can I fix them? I'd rather not have to upload without symbols or bitcode, so if that's the workaround, I'd like to know why, so I'm not limiting myself for something dumb.

Cheers!

Comment: This should be only temporary bug. It happens often to me, and the only solution for this is to wait few hours.

Comment: On other side you can also try to upload with applicationloader with making .ipa file. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36613320/4910767

Comment: @pedrouan That'd be nice, if this hadn't been going on for three days now. Probably should've mentioned that...

Comment: @BadalShah Ew... Does it _have_ to be that way until kingdom come? Sure I'll give it a shot, but it seems terribly cumbersome, and Application Loader still gave me errors when I exported the normal way. How would that be different? And would Apple take an Ad Hoc build over an App Store one?

Comment: @SeizeTheDay Have you an access to Code-Level support within your developer account? If so, try to post your trouble. Because this warning from Xcode is really useless to find out the issue.

Comment: @pedrouan Code-level support.  O_O  That's a thing? I'd best look into that...

Comment: @SeizeTheDay Check here: http://pasteboard.co/4S5xyahig.png. There are two free Technical Support Incidents that you can use at your account during one year.

Comment: @SeizeTheDay this is my own experience. I got some error in the past without any description and then i tried it with application loader then i got exact issue with proper description like , asset catalog error or else. so, i suggest to use application loader.

Comment: @BadalShah AL gave me something about asset catalog, something about P3 assets, but I looked into that and found no such assets anywhere in my ipa. Even redid a bunch of the .xibs and .storyboards in case they were the cause... Gonna try it again at some point in the morning and update my post for more specifics there.  If I may ask, what fixed it for you, if you can recall?

Comment: @BadalShah Probably that iTunes .ipa workaround, right?

Comment: @SeizeTheDay i didn't remembered that actually. but actually when you will try next , take the screenshot of error and edit your question.

Comment: @BadalShah Updated. Got that P3 asset error, but I can confirm that none of my assets read (at least in the .ipa's database) as P3 or 16-bit. There is one thing I could try... Could a vector asset from Inkscape be throwing this? I'll try re-exporting with more specificity on the color space and see what happens.

Comment: No luck with color profile. Inkscape claims the file's already RGB, and the .svg file confirms it. I am noticing that several of my assets don't list a color profile, where the color space says RGB. Would those default to P3 then? Not sure that they ought to...

Comment: Any luck on solving this? I have the same issue...

Comment: @thomax Some. Apple tells me it's a known issue when building to an iOS 8.3 or .4 distribution target. I get the same result when I change to 8.2 (as he told me), so I didn't bother updating the OP. On a related note, I moved a copy of the project to Swift 3, and I get a completely new error! Trying to work both out now.

Comment: FWIW, I quit Xcode, restarted, rebuilt, and validated, with no errors.

Comment: I ignored the 434 error when validating and uploaded anyway and it was accepted. I never got the other error.

Comment: @MastaBaba does it worked

Comment: @RowanPD.. is it good without validating app?

Comment: @UmaMadhavi: Yes, that simply did the trick for me.

Comment: I did upload via `Application Loader`. Either it was just temporary issue, or it is Xcode bug. Btw, `fastalne pilot` also did upload to iTC without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by uploading my app through Application Loader.

1. Archive app   Export ipa iOS Deployment
2. Xcode-> open developer tool -> Application loader

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with Xcode 8.2 while submitting my application:

```
 ITunesSoftwareServiceAuthenticationErrorDomain error 434.
```

**Solution: I switched to different network and it worked for me.**

Comment: Seriously. After switching to a different network, it worked.

Comment: @lujop I switched to some other internet connection network. Then tried uploading the build and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Bump the build number and validate again.

Comment: For me it was the version number.

Comment: I bumped the version number, *and* had to restart after doing so

Answer (score 3):

Had the exact same problem. I tried upgrading to Sierra which seemed to update bits of Xcode etc.  The new error message was formatted differently, so I could not see the "434" 
[image]
(With 1 success in 15 attempts (I had to tweak a version number in a string in the app, so didn't choose to upload after that brief moment of joy), i just uploaded the archive anyway, and after 2 hours of processing, it was accepted. I will update when my new app version is live to verify this error can be safely ignored, at least in some cases (e.g. I checked all my graphics' color profiles, etc.).

Comment: For what it's worth, when this error appears, the error drop-down sheet can be resized to show the complete error message.

Answer (score 2):

Do the below steps :- 
1. Analyze the project. (From Product Menu)
2. Click on Archive. (From Product Menu)
3. Select the development team for provisioning.
4. From summary window **unselect "Include bitcode"** and click on Validate button.
Now, It will working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while I was trying to submit the app to client's iTunesConnect account. I've signed in with new apple id, downloaded the certificates and provisionin profiles but still got this error:

```
(ITunesSoftwareServiceAuthenticationErrorDomain error 434.)
```

How to fix this error?

1. Try to remove Provisioning Profiles files at ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
2. Make new Build and Archive the app. Xcode will create new Provisioning Profiles and submit the app to iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 1):

Just to share this.

Quit xcode and re-login as suggested by members does not work for me. I solved it by using "Application Loader"

Steps: 1) change the version and build in your App 2) archive again for new file submission and export file to desktop 3) goto top menu: Open Developer Tool > Application Loader (if you don't have this , search, download and install this plug init) 4) upload the new version archived file. Done

You will find them in iTune Connect. From here process to My Apps > choose the rejected app > change the version and click on the new uploaded archive file, file will be processing..

5) time to resubmit :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

## Clicked Valid until it succeeded, 3rd time.

Since there seem to be many solutions to this problem, it may just be an issue not related to anything developers have control over and the "solutions" seem to be "solutions" because after some action was taken, it succeeded. The action I took was the non-action... and it was successful.

Hope this helps, as this is a stressful problem to have when you cannot upload your app and muddling around in Xcode to fix it you might break something else.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by upload using Application Loader.
Besides, after upload the app i receive the warning about Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description and Privacy - Camera Usage Description, so that, please make sure you have them in your info

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case it was caused by following. I had a lot of png-files in assets.xcassets and some of them had AdobeRGB Color profile. I changed the profiles to sRGB and xcode validated the archive with no error.
Frankly speaking, when I changed the profiles some other strange errors occured, but they dissapeared by themselves when I tried to re-validate the acrchive several hours later (I did nothing just waited).

Comment: How did you change the profiles from AdobeRGB to sRGB? I really need to know thanks.

Comment: It's very easy. ctrl+click on an image you want to convert, then open with ColorSync Utility. At the bottom select "assign to profile" in the very left menu and in the next menu select profile you need. I use non-english version of iOS, so it may well be that titles of the program and menus will be different, but, anyhow, it's not difficult at all. P.S. this way is not good if you need to perform butch converting. In this case you'd better use photoshop or something.

Comment: Thanks :D I just found that out

Answer (score 0):

If this occurred randomly, try to delete that archive and make sure you have "Generic iOS Device" selected as target when you run Product > Archive again. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I Got the same issues when i try first time.Next time it **Validated** successfully. Please check network once before trying second time.

Answer (score 0):

1.Cmd+Shift+K
2.Close Xcode
3.Open Xcode
4.Cmd+B
5.Product->Archive

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Just Clear all file in Path ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
2. Go to Xcode Select Provisioning profile again and then it auto-generate again.

So It will be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the following:

- my account had been logged out and I had to enter the password again
- Xcode v8.0 had to be updated to 9.x to be able to publish to the App Store (as of July 2018)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by updating Xcode from 8.2 to 9.

Apparently there was a compatibility issue with an SDK used internally. Xcode was not helping with it's error message. I discovered it by using the Application Loader to upload the archive. Application Loader's error message made some sense.