# Xcode 8 archive upload error 434, then Application Loader error: Java heap space

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, xcode8, application-loader

I have experienced similar problem to this (error 434 when uploading an archive to App Store with Xcode 8)

[Strange Errors on Archive Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566481/strange-errors-on-archive-validation)

so I switched to the Application Loader and got following error:

[image: Application Loader fails to upload app]

I double-checked on everything regarding the provisioning stuff, code signing etc. Also, I did all usual troubleshooting steps like clean build, deleting derived data, restarting etc. Still no success. Anyone has dealt with it with success?