# sips shows Unable to render destination image

Tags: macos, sips

I had used sips to resize PNG image as below command.

> sips -z 768 1024 image.png --out image-resize.png

It works well. But today I got an error message as shown in below

```
<CGColor 0x7ffb72e05c40> [<CGColorSpace 0x7ffb72e04e70> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)] ( 0 0 0 1 )
Error: Unable to render destination image
```

If anyone could help it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I solved this problem after reading this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39594655/4948360

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing color profile value from RGB 16bit to 8bit sRGB fixing this problem.

This can be done by one command in Terminal:

```
find . -type f -name '*.png' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do sips --matchTo '/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/sRGB Profile.icc' "$file" --out "$file"; done
```

Then images can be resized by sips. For batch resize I use this command:

```
mdfind -0 -onlyin . "kMDItemPixelHeight > 600 || kMDItemPixelWidth > 600" | xargs -0 sips -Z 600
```

And at finish, this command for reduce size of image files:

```
find . -name '*.png' -exec pngquant --skip-if-larger --ext .png --force {} \; -exec xattr -c {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sips -s format jpeg image.png --out image.jpg
sips -z 768 1024 image.jpg --out image-resize.jpg
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.